# Getting error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'add_filter' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION)

Tags: plugins, screen-options, screen-columns, screen-layout

I am getting error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'add_filter' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION)
```

when i write the below code in my plugin class file. but this is the only easiest method i saw to get the screen options working.
is that code needs to be placed somewhere else?

```
function pippin_set_screen_option($status, $option, $value) {
    if ( 'pippin_per_page' == $option ) return $value;
}
add_filter('set-screen-option', 'pippin_set_screen_option', 10, 3);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "my plugin class"? You wrote a class and you just want to shove that snippet into it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be you have just dropped filter into a class body in between the methods. That is invalid PHP and not going to work.

First you need to call it from where code makes sense, *inside* another class method or from outside a class.

Second you cannot hook methods by their name alone, you need to use proper callback with a name of the class. Examples would be `[ __CLASS__, 'method_name' ]` (static method) or `[ $this, 'method_name' ]` (non-static method in class instance).

And finally if you are new to PHP then spending some time with PHP manual is **highly** recommended, it will save you a lot of time in dealing with WordPress.